# this code works only for some charts like, it will work on btc but not on ltc why?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

this code should to plot a blue line in the middle of the previous day but it's not working only for some charts, and to make things worse the open and high works as it should.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Plot Lines', overlay=true)

PDH = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
PDL = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)

var line l_pdh = na
var line l_pdl = na
var line l_midPoint = na

if barstate.islast
    l_pdh := line.new(bar_index - 1, PDH[1], bar_index, PDH[1], extend=extend.both,color=color.green)
    l_pdl := line.new(bar_index - 1,PDL[1],bar_index,PDL[1],extend=extend.both,color=color.red)

    // Calculate midpoint between high and low
    midPoint = (PDH + PDL) / 2

    // Plot blue open line at midpoint
    l_midPoint := line.new(bar_index - 1,midPoint ,bar_index,midPoint ,extend=extend.both,color=color.blue)

line.delete(l_pdh[1])
line.delete(l_pdl[1])
line.delete(l_midPoint[1])
```

[chart one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z973Y.jpg)
[chart two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0azi.jpg)

Comment: please edit your question and format your code

Answer (score 1):

*midPoint* must have the [previous values](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_%5B%5D) (from the previous day)
something like that:

```
//@version=5

indicator('Plot Lines', overlay=true)

PDH = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', high)
PDL = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', low)

var line l_pdh = na
var line l_pdl = na
var line l_midPoint = na

if barstate.islast
    l_pdh := line.new(bar_index - 1, PDH[1], bar_index, PDH[1], extend = extend.both, color = color.green)
    l_pdl := line.new(bar_index - 1, PDL[1], bar_index, PDL[1], extend = extend.both, color = color.red)
    // Calculate midpoint between high and low
    midPoint = (PDH[1] + PDL[1]) / 2
    // Plot blue open line at midpoint
    l_midPoint := line.new(bar_index - 1,midPoint ,bar_index,midPoint ,extend = extend.both,color = color.blue)

line.delete(l_pdh[1])
line.delete(l_pdl[1])
line.delete(l_midPoint[1])
```